# Mysql, Successful Query, But no results are entered into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an insert query, which operates fine, But I've got to add another field to it from a table outside of the query. I figured I would do this with another Join, But all that does is runs the query successfully and displays no results in the DB.

```
INSERT INTO m_aa_rma_items
(
    web_rma_id,
    sku,
    reason,
    resolution,
    item_name,
    aa_rma_id
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    m_rma_item.rma_id, 
    catalog_product_entity.sku,
    m_rma_item.reason_id, 
    m_rma_item.resolution_id, 
    m_rma_item.name,
    m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id
FROM m_rma_item    
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON m_rma_item.product_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id                        
    INNER JOIN m_rma_rma ON m_rma_rma.rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id    
    INNER JOIN m_aa_rma_rma ON m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id    
WHERE m_rma_rma.status_id= "2"
```

In a previous query, Data is entered into the `m_aa_rma_rma` table, Obviously I am putting related items into the `m_aa_rma_items` table. If one takes out the last `INNER JOIN` and the fields `aa_rma_id` and `m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id` this query functions like it is supposed to. 
    What I am trying to get accomplished is putting the related ID(`aa_rma_id`) into the field `aa_rma_id` in the `m_aa_rma_items`table. I hope I have been thorough enough and coherent enough to make sense of it. Where am I going wrong with this query to achieve this goal?

Comment: Hint: a SELECT query that doesn't return rows is not considered an error.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are doing an `INNER JOIN` which gives only matching rows. So, if there is no matching row then you end up inserting 0 rows to the destination table. If you doubt that the last `JOIN` causing issue then change it to a `LEFT JOIN` instead like below and verify the `INSERT`

```
LEFT JOIN m_aa_rma_rma
ON m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure about your table structures. So with a little guess, try the below modified query

```
INSERT INTO m_aa_rma_items(         web_rma_id,
                                    sku,
                                    reason,
                                    resolution,
                                    item_name,
                                    aa_rma_id
                                )
                    SELECT DISTINCT m_rma_item.rma_id, 
                                    catalog_product_entity.sku,
                                    m_rma_item.reason_id, 
                                    m_rma_item.resolution_id, 
                                    m_rma_item.name,
                                    m_rma_item.rma_id

                    FROM m_rma_item

                    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity
                    ON m_rma_item.product_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id

                    INNER JOIN m_rma_rma
                    ON m_rma_rma.rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id
                    AND m_rma_rma.status_id= "2"

                    LEFT JOIN m_aa_rma_rma
                    ON m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id;
```

Comment: Ok, I changed it to a `LEFT JOIN` This did in fact allow the rows to add, But it didn't push the `m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id` value into the `m_aa_rma_items.aa_rma_id` field. Obviously, I am Pretty new to mysql is there an easier more efficient way of doing this? its basically defining a relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Not sure about your table structure but try the edited query in answer.

Comment: That query is functional, But is still doesn't pull the `aa_rma_id' fields accordingly their values are still zero. Also it pulls all of the records out of the `m_rma_item` table instead of the select ones. What would be the best way to define the table structure so that you could have a better understanding of what I am seeing.

Comment: Mind trying again. Check the edited query in answer. basically `m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id` field not getting inserted cause there is no match.

Comment: I can't pin point what you changed, but now its pulling the `web_rma_id` Over into the `aa_rma_id` field. This is better than what it was doing before with the zero's.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, Sir. But there was match's within the tables. Without your guidance, i wouldn't have been able to spot the error, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO m_aa_rma_items(         web_rma_id,
                                    sku,
                                    reason,
                                    resolution,
                                    item_name,
                                    aa_rma_id
                                )
                    SELECT DISTINCT m_rma_item.rma_id, 
                                    catalog_product_entity.sku,
                                    m_rma_item.reason_id, 
                                    m_rma_item.resolution_id, 
                                    m_rma_item.name,
                                    m_aa_rma_rma.aa_rma_id

                    FROM m_rma_item

                    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity
                    ON m_rma_item.product_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id

                    INNER JOIN m_rma_rma
                    ON m_rma_rma.rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id
                    AND m_rma_rma.status_id= "2"

                    LEFT JOIN m_aa_rma_rma
                    ON m_aa_rma_rma.web_rma_id = m_rma_item.rma_id;
```